# Find sum of the element in array and compare it with input in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an input like:

```
{ 
"begin": "2010-01-01", 
"end": "2015-01-01", 
"min": 4, 
"max": 10 
}
```

and I want to use this input to analyze the data coming from a MongoDB collection called `grade` with the following format:

```
[{
    "createdAt": "2010-01-01T09:00:00.000Z",
    "grade": [
        2,
        1
    ]
},
{
    "createdAt": "2011-01-01T00:00:10.398Z",
    "grade": [
        1,
        5,
        3
    ]
}]
```

My query should work like:

```
SELECT * FROM grade WHERE createdAT > begin AND createdAT < end AND sum(grade) > min AND sum(grade) < max
```

my code in mongo is like:

```
grade.find({
        createdAt: {
            $gte: begin,
            $lt: end
        },
        grade: {
            $gte: min,
            $lt: max 
        }

    })
```

I don't know how to sum up the grade array and then make compare.

The response should be:

```
{
"createdAt": "2011-01-01T00:00:10.398Z",
"totalGrade": 9
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation for this

```
db.grade.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        createdAt:1,
        totalGrade: {$sum: "$grade"}
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        createdAt: {
            $gte: begin,
            $lt: end
        },
        totalGrade: {
            $gte: min,
            $lt: max 
        }
    }
}])
```